# How to convert/store a double precision (64bit) number to a 32 bit float or a UInt16 in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Assume I can bare the loss of digits/precision to some degree. I find that to send a 64bit (8 bytes) number over the network sometimes is overkilled. I want the data to use less bandwidth but maintain certain accuracy. But I don't know the correct way to store a number in 32 bit or 16 bit data in javascript.

Comment: What format are you using to send data over the network? If it's JSON, the entire point is moot I think.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen its binary data. I convert it to array buffer using msgpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can convert a JavaScript number to an array buffer holding a 32 bit float or a 16 bit unsigned integer:

```js
let float64 = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197;

let float32View = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));
float32View.setFloat32(0, float64);

let uint16View = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(2));
uint16View.setUint16(0, float64);

console.log(float64);
console.log(float32View.getFloat32(0));
console.log(uint16View.getUint16(0));
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I am looking for. Although it looks a bit cumbersome. If I do this at a high frequency will it use too much CPU power or memory? Considering I need to new two instances in a single operation.

Comment: You can do all your conversions using one `ArrayBuffer` and one `DataView`. Just need to keep track of your byte offsets.

Comment: Oh yes you mean using `setFloat32()` multiple times? Very nice.

Comment: Yup, just need to use to keep incrementing your byte offset by 4 and make sure your buffer is big enough.

Comment: Which one is the offset? the first argument of `setFloat(arg1, arg2)` or `setUint16(arg1, arg2)`? But I guess if my float numbers are generated at run time at high frequency I still can't get away with this. Because in my situation I can't just send one packet per second anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the first argument. Have you looked into [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)?

Comment: Yes I have read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays. But I couldn't see the methods you mentioned here. I think it is because the methods are inside `DataView` which I happened to ignore when I skimmed the texts. And the way you do it is different from creating a new typed array. Creating a new typed array can be found in this demo: https://repl.it/HXTN/2